# Composer with alias: Could not open input file

Tags: composer-php, alias

I know this questions has been asked here many many times, but I couldn't find my specific case. I'm on shared hosting with SSH access on Debian. When executing the command

```
/usr/bin/php7.1-cli /xxxxxxxxx/www/composer.phar
```

it runs perfectly in any folder. When putting the same command 1:1 into an alias in bashrc like

```
alias composer='/usr/bin/php7.1-cli /xxxxxxxxx/www/composer.phar'
```

I get the "Could not open input file" error. What am I missing?

EDIT: When showing the aliases through the command "alias" in every line except one the "a" of the word "alias" is replaced by an apostrophe:

```
'lias composer='/usr/bin/php7.1-cli /xxxxxxxxx/www/composer.phar'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after changing the .bash_profile file from CR+LF to LF it is correctly processed. This didn't work with .bashrc, but this partial success is sufficient for me now.